# python ImportError No module named "xxx" but in the same dir, other file can be imported

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a project look like this(the real project is more complicated)

```
src
 |
 +---- run.py
 |
 +---- branch1
 |
 +---- branch2
 |
 +---- branch3
         |
         +---- __init__.py
         +---- a.py
         +---- b.py
         +---- c.py
```

in run.py there is :

```
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

actually, at first I do not hava c.py and when I run run.py in src, everything is perfect, but after I created c.py, and I imported c.py to b.py which will be used when I run run.py:

```
from branch3.c import Ccalss
```

but the error occured:

```
ImportError: No module named c.py
```

but I can import any other module like a.py to b.py and it works fine.

how could this happen? afer I created c.py, need I modify any path?
to add this single module to sys.path? if this dir brach3 is already in the path, need I add c.py to path separately?

I can not believe that I have to add every .py file separately to path in a project....

I'm new to python, And I noticed there are questions with the same problem, but all the answers says sys.path.append... I still confused about this, And I have no reputation to comment....

Comment: Not sure about this but do you have `__all__=['a','b','c']` in `__init__.py`. This is needed when you do `from branch3 import *` and it may be totally unrelated...

Comment: have you googled `sys.path.append`?

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus I have, and I noticed that in the main of run.py it has sys.path.append(os.getcwd()), and my cwd is src, then I can not understand the problem

Comment: @urban isn't __all__ only effect when I use somtethin like "from src import *" ?

Comment: @kknight: Yes I think so but I am not 100% sure and I cannot see anything else being wrong!